# ¿Cómo acortar css mediante jquery para sustituir valores de forma rápida y sencilla?

Tags: jquery, html, css

En el código que sigue se me complica bastante la tarea de sustituir valores para hacer pruebas. Me gustaría que las clases `squareX` aplicasen el valor de su background a las clases `colorX` con la opacidad escogida.

```css
.square0{position:absolute; left:0%; width:50px;height:50px; bottom:0px;z-index:2000; border:1px solid black; background: rgba(57,231,181,0.80);}
.square1{position:absolute; left:0%; width:50px;height:50px; bottom:50px;z-index:2000;border:1px solid black;background:rgba(130,242,240,0.80);}
.square2{position:absolute; left:0%; width:50px;height:50px; bottom:100px;z-index:2000;border:1px solid black;background: rgba(230,235,80,0.70);}
.square3{position:absolute; left:0%; width:50px;height:50px; bottom:150px;z-index:2000;border:1px solid black;background: rgba(244,238,162,0.80) ;}

.bg0a{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(57,231,181,0.80) 1% 
 , rgba(57,231,181,0.00) 70%);
}
.bg0b{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(57,231,181,0.50) 1% 
 , rgba(57,231,181,0.0) 70%);
}
.bg1a{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(130,242,240,0.80) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(130,242,240,0.80) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(130,242,240,0.80) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(130,242,240,0.80) 5% 
 , rgba(130,242,240,0.00) 70%);
}
.bg1b{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(130,242,240,0.50) 1% 
 , rgba(130,242,240,0.0) 70%);
}
.bg2a{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(230,235,80,0.7) 5% 
 , rgba(230,235,80,0.00) 70%);
}
.bg2b{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(230,235,80,0.35) 1% 
 , rgba(230,235,80,0.0) 70%);
}
.bg2c{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(230,235,80,0.1) 1% 
 , rgba(230,235,80,0.0) 70%);
}
.bg3a{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 5% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.1) 70%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(244,238,162,0.60)5% 
 , rgba(244,238,162,0.00) 70%);
}
.bg3b{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(244,238,162,0.40) 1% 
 , rgba(244,238,162,0.0) 70%);
}

.bg3c{
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(231,231,231,1.00) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(253,255,0,0.10) 1% 
 , rgba(231,231,231,0.0) 40%); 
 background: radial-gradient(circle,rgba(244,238,162,0.20) 50% 
 , rgba(244,238,162,0.0) 70%);
}
.circle {
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%; 
 position:absolute;
 z-index:50;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square0"></div>
<div class="square1"></div>
<div class="square2"></div>
<div class="square3"></div>

<div class="circle bg0a"></div>
<div class="circle bg1a" style="position:absolute; left:200px;"></div>
<div class="circle bg2a" style="position:absolute; left:400px;"></div>
<div class="circle bg3a" style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:200px;"></div>
```

Al estar cada uno repetido varias veces para cada navegador, hay alguna forma de que el valor de color de los `#square` se aplique a su correspondiente clase de color con la opacidad escogida.

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías intentar con _mixins_, pero son en diseño, no en el front-end. Yo uso [sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6), pero en [less](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) son casi idénticos.

Comment: Wow! No he entendido nada pero voy a investigar. Gracias @toledano

Comment: El CSS es bastante limitado. Como te dice @toledano, una opción es usar preprocesadores de CSS para escribir menos. No puedes usar jquery ya que únicamente actúa sobre el árbol DOM, no sobre los estilos definidos en la página. Mi recomendación es que te busques un editor con [snippets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_%28programming%29) y que te crees una plantilla. Por ejemplo, gedit

Comment: Agregando a lo que dice @toledano, un par de enlaces que te serán de utilidad: https://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/ y http://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus Esa actitud que tienes de "No he entendido nada pero **voy a investigar**" hace una enorme diferencia, sigue adelante con todo el power!!! Éxitos y bendiciones :D

Comment: Gracias a todos, a ver si puedo publicar pronto la solución!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es más menos como puedes escribir tu código usanso SASS. Como ya te comentaron el CSS es muy limitado y por eso han surgido los lenguajes preprocesadores como [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) y [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Para generar los estilos copia el código que te pongo a continuación en un nuevo fichero con extensión `.scss` e instala el preprocesador siguiendo las [instrucciones](http://sass-lang.com/install) de la documentación.

*Estilos.scss*

```
// Squares
$square_colors: rgba(57, 231, 181, 0.80), rgba(57, 231, 181, 0.80), rgba(130, 242, 240, 0.80), rgba(230, 235, 80, 0.70);

@for $i from 0 through length($square_colors) - 1 {

  // declaración de la clase

  .square#{$i} {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0 + $i * 50px;
    z-index: 2000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: nth($square_colors, $i + 1);
  }
}

// Circles

$letters: 'a', 'b', 'c';

@mixin circulo($color, $opacity, $stop) {
  $opacity: 80% !default;
  $stop: 1% !default;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba($color, $opacity) $stop, rgba($color, 0) 70%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba($color, $opacity) $stop, rgba($color, 0.00) 70%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba($color, $opacity) $stop, rgba($color, 0.00) 70%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba($color, $opacity) $stop, rgba($color, 0.00) 70%);
}

$circle_colors: (
        (
                color: rgb(57, 231, 181),
                settings: ((opacity: 0.80, stop: 1%), (opacity: 0.50, stop: 1%))
        ),
        (
                color: rgb(130, 242, 240),
                settings: ((opacity: 0.80, stop: 5%), (opacity: 0.50, stop: 1%))
        ),
        (
                color: rgb(230, 235, 80),
                settings: ((opacity: 0.7, stop: 5%), (opacity: 0.35, stop: 1%), (opacity: 0.1, stop: 1%))
        ),
        (
                color: rgb(244, 238, 162),
                settings: ((opacity: 0.60, stop: 5%), (opacity: 0.40, stop: 1%), (opacity: 0.20, stop: 50%))
        )
);

@for $i from 0 through length($circle_colors) - 1 {
  $current: nth($circle_colors, $i + 1);
  $settings: map_get($current, 'settings');
  @for $j from 0 through length($settings) - 1 {
    $letter: nth($letters, $j + 1);
    $setting: nth($settings, $j + 1);

    // declaración de la clase

    .bg#{$i}#{$letter} {
      @include circulo(map_get($current, 'color'), map_get($setting, 'opacity'), map_get($setting, 'stop'));
    }
  }
}

// declaracion de la clase
.circle {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Luego ejecuta algo cómo

```
sass estilos.scss estilos.css
```

y encontraras un fichero `estilos.css` con tus estilos compilados.

No logré encontrar un patrón para los círculos por lo que agregé una variable en la que puedes agregar algunos elementos nuevos y generar nuevas clases. Todo esto se puede reducir mucho más si usas alguna fórmula matematica para generar los colores. Sass tiene muchas [funciones](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) para eso.

Tu código html se mantiene igual pero como ves solo necesito declarar tres clases en los lugares comentados para generar todo el CSS que tenías que crear manualmente.